# Two instructions in the same line of code

Tags: java, optimization, format

Is it possible to code two instructions in the same line of code?

I know i can do this:

```
if (b < -1 && element.compareTo(node.getRight().getElement()) > 0) return leftRotation(node);
```

But currently i have this:

```
if (b > 1 && element.compareTo(node.getLeft().getElement()) > 0) {
        node.setLeft(leftRotation(node.getLeft()));
        return rightRotation(node);
}
```

Is it possible to put the *node.setLeft()* and the *return* statement in the same line of code?

Comment: Yes. You can just delete the line break between the two lines. I don't know what advantage you imagine that might convey.

Comment: Yes, just don't make a line break after the `{`. Newlines don't have any semantic meaning in Java. But why would you want to?

Comment: It begs the question... Why?  And how do you define "a line of code"?  The carriage return is optional as far as the compiler is concerned, so you can just put both statements on the same line in the file.  Or you could write a method which performs the first statement and returns the second, then just return a call to that method.

Comment: This will probably confuse future maintainers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The obvious answer:

Put `{ statement1; statement2; }` all on one line. In fact, you can remove all newlines from your java file and it compiles just the same. Obviously, don't do this; you'd get an unreadable mess!

A more useful answer:

Think about your API design. In this case, perhaps the `setLeft` method of node should return itself, instead of returning void. Then you could write: return `rightRotation(node.setLeft(leftRotation(node.getLeft()));`. Or, even better, if leftRotation and rightRotation are methods on node itself: `return node.setLeft(node.getLeft().rotateLeft()).rotateRight();`

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Because `setLeft` definition is probably this:

```
public void setLeft(int left) {
    this.left = left;
}
```

So, you can't return a `void` returning method execution result.